# Arango logs: "process is near the maximum number of memory mappings. current: 628544, maximum: 512000."

Tags: arangodb

On a single instance, running on a 8 core VM, we see the following log entry:

`process is near the maximum number of memory mappings. current: 628544, maximum: 512000. it may be sensible to increase the maximum number of mappings per process`

Arango did not crash so far but what do we have to do to tune the system?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to run `sysctl -w 'vm.max_map_count=2048000'` before running arangodb. Do not forget to make this setting **permanent**.

For more info have a look into the documentation:
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/administration-reduce-memory-footprint.html

Comment: And how could I run this command, when my ArangoDB runs in a Docker Container. I am using Docker Desktop.